# Groovy closures (Multiple Shell commands in one closure function groovy)

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i have the below commands in groovy and i want to define them in a single closure function and pass the parameters accordingly.

Example:

```
sh "curl -0 https://url.com/path1/somefile.1
    curl -0 https://url.com/path2/somefile.2
    curl -0 https://url.com/path3/somefile.3
    aws s3 copy ./somefile.1 s3:bucket
    aws s3 copy ./somefile.2 s3:bucket
    aws s3 copy ./somefile.3 s3:bucket"
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. I am following the  tutorials in tutorial points in building the closures but not clear to me from that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 def mp = ["somefile.1" : "path1", "somefile.2" : "path2","somefile.3" : "path3"]             

     mp.each {sh """curl -0 https://url.com/${it.value}/${it.key}
      aws s3 copy ./${it.key} s3:bucket"""}
```